# Using optional arguments of overloaded TypeScript methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading

I'm using a package written in TS in a JS app. I have a method with multiple overloads:

```
overloadedMethod(stringParameter: string): void;
overloadedMethod(stringParameter: string, otherParameter: any): void;
```

And I call it like this:

```
if (!myOtherParameter) {
    overloadedMethod(myStringParameter)
} else {
    overloadedMethod(myStringParameter, myOtherParameter)
}
```

I do not like this one bit. Have I approached the problem incorrectly, or is there some way I can include the `otherParameter` only if it is not undefined or null?

Comment: If a method has both overloads, then you can use either to call it. Why would only calling `overloadedMethod(myStringParameter, myOtherParameter)` be a problem?

Comment: Sometimes `myOtherParameter` is null or undefined. The package containing `overloadedMethod` runs the code associated with having `myOtherParameter` and things end badly.

Comment: If you control the package, the sensible thing is to use default values for `null`. If you don't control the package, you can try `overloadedMethod(myStringParameter, myOtherParameter ?? undefined)` which will pass `undefined` instead of `null`. That *might* work depending on how the optional argument is implemented. If *that* doesn't work, then honestly your approach seems sensible. Because the API you consume isn't.

Comment: You *could* make something like `overloadedMethod(...[myStringParameter, myOtherParameter].filter(x => x != null))` and maybe enclose that into a reusable function so you call something like `overloadedMethod(...onlyRelevantArgs(myStringParameter, myOtherParameter))` but it's probably over-engineering it.